# adding to table a column with serial numbers that based on information in two columns

Tags: postgresql, sorting

I have a 100 rows table ("GendersHeight") with two columns: the 1st column ("gender") is a string ("male" or "female"). the 2nd column ("height") is a variable number. I sorted the table based on these two columns accordingly:

```
select *
into MyNewTable 
from GendersHeight
order by gender, height DESC
```

(there are 40 "male" rows, and 60 "female" rows in my table)
Now I'd like to add a new column (3rd column) to table "MyNewTable" that holds a serial number.
If I'll use the script:

```
ALTER TABLE MyNewTable
Add column MySorter serial NOT NULL;
```

I'll just get a serial column that ranges from 1 to 100. 
BUT - what I want really to achieve here is creating a column that would range from 1 to 60 first, for all the "female" entries, and then would range from 1 to 40 for all the "male" entries. 
Is there a way to create such a serial column that is taking in account the nature of the "gender" column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [rank()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/tutorial-window.html) function:

```
CREATE TABLE "MyNewTable" AS
SELECT gender,
    height,
   rank() OVER(partition by gender order by height) as myrank
 FROM "GendersHeight"
```

Comment: thanks a lot minth! - this solution is wonderful!! exactly what i needed. I could definitely create an additional table that would hold the result of my new sorting/ordering. Great!